# Make some logic depending of get Response

Tags: java, spring-boot, get, response

I'm training with Spring Boot , and I want to call a GET type web service who returns a JSON, and I only want to retrieve the status of the response to use it later

Is it possible ?

Here is a part of my code :

**The call Function** :

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = getUser(username);
```

**The function** :

```
@GetMapping("/users")
public ResponseEntity<String> getUser(@RequestParam("username") String username) {

    //if(ResponseEntity.ok().build().)}
```

Anyone can help me to finish this logic please ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why? A get will have a response body otherwise it not getting anything. the status only the status of the request.
Maybe a get is not appropriate?

Comment: I need the response status because after that, I should call function depending of status code, if status code is ok --> call a function 
          if status code not ok --> call another function

Comment: A web service is a service, if you need to make the decision on what to do them the service should return a result that enables the caller to decide what to do next.
The status of the call should always be 200 unless something goes wrong.